# Advice on a paid for streaming solution please

Tags: streaming, audio-streaming

I have a potential project for which the client has asked for the ability for people to visit a website and pay to hear an audio file.

They have an attraction and would like people to pay a nominal amount (£1) for them to listen to a short story as they wander round.

My thoughts were to have some sort of paywall streaming service integrated into his website so that they have no issues over hosting/bandwidth.

My research, however is drawing blanks. Most streaming services are set up for video, radio stations, or the fees involved wouldn't be worth paying at £1 a shot.

Both he client and myself are only expecting a few hundred streams every year, and the fee is really just to raise funds for local charity, so this is a pretty low level operation.

Does anyone have any advice in this area please?

Answer (score 0):

If the total income will be just several hundred pounds per year, then I suspect it might be easier and even more profitable to just have a donations bucket at the venue.

If you do want to have some sort of online payment, then for the type of low monetary value content, i.e. people are unlikely to put the time and effort into circumventing the payment or pirating the content, a simple paywall before exposing the link to the audio may be fine.

There are also many open source audio streaming solutions and audio bandwidth is actually quite low by todays standards so actually hosting the audio may be easier that you expect. A goos list of servers is here:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_streaming_media_systems

Answer (score 0):

You don't need anything special for a pre-recorded audio file streaming.  Any HTTP server would do just fine.

I would handle this by uploading your media file to an S3 bucket, with no public read permissions.  Then, once someone has paid, use a key pair that does have read permissions to sign a URL so that the client can access it.  Then, just play that file client-side in a normal `<audio>` tag like anything else.

Comment: Well that all sounds great, but I've no idea how to make any of it work!